# Add an iterative legend to a python function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, legend

I have 2 functions, 'one function calling other' to plot some curves. What I want is to have legends in these functions that can be seen as one in the final plot, but I am unable to achieve that. Can someone help me with this? Code below (works fine without the label/legend lines).

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

def gradient_fill(x, y, fill_color=None, ax=None, label = None, **kwargs):
    """
    Plot a line with a linear alpha gradient filled beneath it.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : array-like
        The data values of the line.
    """
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    line, = ax.plot(x, y, **kwargs, color='black', lw = 1.5)
    if fill_color is None:
        fill_color = line.get_color()

    zorder = line.get_zorder()
    alpha = line.get_alpha()
    alpha = 1.0 if alpha is None else alpha

    z = np.empty((100, 1, 4), dtype=float)
    rgb = mcolors.colorConverter.to_rgb(fill_color)
    z[:,:,:3] = rgb
    z[:,:,-1] = np.linspace(0, alpha, 100)[:,None]

    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()
    im = ax.imshow(z, aspect='auto', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax*1.12],
                   origin='lower', zorder=zorder,alpha = 0.8, label = label)
    ax.legend([str(label)])    
    xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
    xy = np.vstack([[xmin, ymin], xy, [xmax, ymin], [xmin, ymin]])
    clip_path = Polygon(xy, facecolor='none', edgecolor= None, closed=True)
    ax.add_patch(clip_path)
    im.set_clip_path(clip_path)
    ax.autoscale(True)
    return line, im

def gaussian_kde(data,bandwidth = 20,x_range_st = -50,x_range_end = 1000, N = 1000, fill_color = None, label = None):
    from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
    # instantiate and fit the KDE model
    kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=bandwidth, kernel='gaussian')
    kde.fit(data[:, None])
    x_d = np.linspace(x_range_st, x_range_end, N)
    # score_samples returns the log of the probability density
    logprob = kde.score_samples(x_d[:, None])
    #plt.fill_between(x_d, np.exp(logprob), alpha=0.5)
    gradient_fill(x_d,np.exp(logprob), fill_color = fill_color, label = label)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

Example of the code:

```
gaussian_kde(data1, label = 'Apple')
gaussian_kde(data2, label = 'Banana', fill_color = 'red')
gaussian_kde(data3, label = 'Mango', fill_color = 'green')
```

[image]

I want to add label directly in the `gaussian_kde` function so that it appears in the final figure. The error I get with the code `TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration`. **The code works fine, but only displays the last label**. Can someone provide some guidance on how to get all the labels as also defined in the figure?

Comment: Matplotlib does not support automatic legends for images. You can use `ax.legend([plt.Rectangle([0,0],1,1, color="green")])`; or else be more precise about what the desired output should be.

Comment: But there is already `ax.legend(im)` defined in the `gradient_fill` function. I just want the legends with the figure, even if I call the function multiple times.

Comment: Delete the line `ax.legend(im)`, because, as commented above, Matplotlib does not support automatic legends for images.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks for the correction. I have edited the figure, with what I want and what I get.

Comment: `ax.legend([plt.Rectangle([0,0],1,1, color="green"), plt.Rectangle([0,0],1,1, color="red")], ["Apple", "Banana"])` then?

Comment: Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Get's the job done, but still quite indirect. What if we had a lot of variables and had to do this multiple times. Nonetheless, calling legend later works fine.

Comment: You can return a rectangle (or circle or whatever) in the color you later need for the legend from the function, and put them all in a list and create the legend from that list.